# Unable to canonicalize address localhost/<unresolved>:2222 because it's not resolvable

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hbase

I want to connect Java with Hbase i get an error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address

```
localhost/<unresolved>:2222 because it's not resolvable
    at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:65)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:41)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1001)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1060)
```

Here is my code:

```
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase");
    conf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "hbase.cluster.distributed");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir", "/home/trannguyenhan/app/hbase-2.4.2/zookeeper");
    conf.set("dfs.replication", "1");
    
    HTable htable = new HTable(conf, "demo");
    
    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("demo_column"), Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("Nguyen Quang Huy"));
    
    htable.put(p);
    htable.close();
```

my configurations are the same as those in the file hbase-site.xml.
Can you help me, thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure zookeeper is running on port 2222 because Zookeeper client default port is 2181.

> telnet localhost 2222

To have HBase manage a ZooKeeper quorum on nodes, bound to port 2222 (the default is 2181) ensure `HBASE_MANAGE_ZK` is commented out or set to true in `conf/hbase-env.sh` and then edit `conf/hbase-site.xml` and set `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` and `hbase.zookeeper.quorum`.

example of hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>./tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://server1:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>zkserver1,zkserver2,zkserver3</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
  </property>
```

Also you must set `hbase.cluster.distributed` as `true` NOT `hbase.cluster.distributed`.
Change

```
    conf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "hbase.cluster.distributed");
```

to

```
conf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
```